# Does any macOS email client besides Outlook allow use of public shared folders in Exchange?

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office

I like some other email clients better than Outlook but none seems to be able to access the public shared folders in our Exchange server.

Apple Mail can not access Exchange public folders. There is no way to subscribe that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

A quick web search throws up [eM Client](https://www.emclient.com/em-with-microsoft-exchange) and its web page includes "Work with your emails (including Shared folders, Public folders, etc.)"

I expect there are others.

Comment: Never heard of it, Checking thanks